# Ruby on Rails RVM $PATH issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I used https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ to install ruby (ruby 1.9.2p290) & gems (no problems), then installed rails via `gem install rails` (Rails 3.2.0), but when I try and create a rails app (or issue `rails -v`) in another directory other than my /user directory I get:

```bash
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing: 
sudo apt-get install rails
```

I also noticed that if I issue `ruby -v`, I get:

```bash
The program 'ruby' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing: 
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

Obviously, this is a $PATH issue, but it's been so long since I've had to do this that I've totally forgotten how to fix the issue.

As far as I can tell, as long as I create an app or issue command version commands in my /user directory, all goes well.

A few things that might help as well:

`which rails` gives me: /home/j3/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rails

`which ruby` gives me: /home/j3/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby

Comment: try `rvm list ` and `rvm use 1.9.2`, what are the results?

Comment: rvm list and rvm use 1.9.2 gives me "No command 'rvm' found, but there are 19 similar ones rvm: command not found" ...now, if I issue this command in my /user directory, all is well.

Comment: check your .bashrc and .bash_profile and see if it is missing the line to add rvm to path

Comment: goodness, I think you had the same problem as I did the last time. Delete your .bash_profile (since you are really just using .bash_rc)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Seems like your rvm has not been added to PATH properly (or it was broken).

Add this line to your profile settings (.bashrc or .bash_profile)

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

and source the file:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

**Edit:** You seem to have added the echo line to .bashrc by mistake, it should be executed in terminal.

Comment: I thought the line I was suppose to add was: echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Yes, it will add the intended line to .bash_profile *if* you run it as a command. But now it is probably less confusing for you to add it by hand as I described.

Comment: Here's my bashrc and bash_profile, do you see anything wrong with either? http://pastie.org/3256496

Comment: yes, remove the echo statements at the bottom of your .bashrc and  .bash_profile, as well as the extra statements starting with [[ (you just need one of them)

Comment: Wait a second, I think it worked!...going to confirm this though.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thank you! That was the issue. Got rid of the parts you mentioned and only added it to my .bashrc file then source ~/.bashrc.

Comment: Good answer.  After re-installing RVM with Ruby, I was getting this error (ruby on rails warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH) from RubyMine.  Adding the line above to my ~/.bashrc file cleared the error.

Answer (score 5):

When you try to create a new rails app in whichever directory you are in, be sure to type `rvm use {ruby version}` and you can also set a default by using `rvm use --default {ruby version}` to use that rvm version of ruby whenever you load a new terminal up.