# Trouble deploying my Rails app to Linode VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, linode

I am trying to deploy my rails app to Linode VPS but after i finished all steps when i did
`xxx@xxxx-desktop:~/myrailsapp$ cap deploy:cold`

i got following error:

```
failed: "env PATH=$HOME/.rvm/shims:$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH sh -c 'cd /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/releases/20130422101521 && bundle install --gemfile /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/releases/20130422101521/Gemfile --path /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

full log is below:

```
xxx@xxx-desktop:~/myrailsapp$ cap deploy:cold
  * 2013-04-22 15:44:59 executing `deploy:cold'
  * 2013-04-22 15:44:59 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2013-04-22 15:44:59 executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:myrailsapp/myrailsapp.git master"
    command finished in 5385ms
  * executing "if [ -d /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 88641306c92790d13f95beb7a2826a072ab72df4 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q git@bitbucket.org:myrailsapp/myrailsapp.git maste /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 88641306c92790d13f95beb7a2826a072ab72df4; fi"
    servers: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
Password: 
    [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 5786ms
    copying the cached version to /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/releases/20130422101521
  * executing "cp -RPp /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/shared/cached-copy /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/releases/20130422101521 && (echo 88641306c92790d13f95beb7a2826a072ab72df4 > /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/releases/20130422101521/REVISION)"
    servers: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
    [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 951ms
  * 2013-04-22 15:45:22 executing `deploy:finalize_update'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * 2013-04-22 15:45:22 executing `deploy:assets:symlink'
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/releases/20130422101521/public/assets && mkdir -p /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/releases/20130422101521/public && mkdir -p /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/shared/assets && ln -s /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/shared/assets /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/releases/20130422101521/public/assets"
    servers: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
    [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 993ms
  * 2013-04-22 15:45:23 executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/releases/20130422101521 && bundle install --gemfile /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/releases/20130422101521/Gemfile --path /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
    [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] executing command
 ** [out :: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
    command finished in 974ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/releases/20130422101521; true"
    servers: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
    [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 971ms
failed: "env PATH=$HOME/.rvm/shims:$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH sh -c 'cd /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/releases/20130422101521 && bundle install --gemfile /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/releases/20130422101521/Gemfile --path /home/deployer/apps/myrailsapp/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error:

```
Bundler is not installed
```

Before in your linode server you must install bundler with:

```
gem install bundler
```

Also, You must add in top to your `deploy.rb`

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
```

Also, you problem is rvm has not been added to PATH:

You can take a look to this question:

[Ruby on Rails RVM $PATH issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018598/ruby-rails-rvm-path-issue)

Regards!

Comment: i already did gem install bundler in my project folder and also i added require "bundler/capistrano" in my deploy.rb file but problem coudn't solved someone suggest me to do following: set :default_environment, {

'PATH' => "$HOME/.rvm/shims:$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH"
} is this right codes ,i have rvm installed in my computer as well as on Linode VPS ?

Comment: No rvm already installed in right path in .bashrc, Actually someone suggest me to add rvm path to deploy.rb file so cold setup will find bundler, but still my problem unresolved, could you check it?